# Deploying Tweetr AS3 site on ISS without cURL

Tags: php, curl, iis, twitter

I've been developing a site for a client that uses the Tweetr API to post messages to a user's Twitter account.  It has now been discovered that the destination server is running IIS, so no mod_rewrite for the Tweetr proxy.  Also cURL is not available, which prevents the proxy from forwarding requests.

The lack of mod_rewrite can be got around, but I need an alternative to using cURL that doesn't require anything not included in a very basic PHP 5.2 install.  I'm considering trying to recreate the proxy functionality with jQuery AJAX, but at the same time that seems like a very lengthy solution.  Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that [this](http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/nov/http-post-from-php-without-curl/) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I think it might be too.  At the moment I'm still debating hacking this into the Tweetr proxy script or just writing my own.  Any recommendations?

Comment: How messy would it actually have to be?

Comment: Involves pretty much replacing the transport method in the proxy. LLoks like the best option though.